# Looking for books and non-paywalled websites about Enigma "rapid analytic machinery"

Tags: enigma

I am by now perfectly aware that "Bletchley Park had much more available to them than 'Bombes,'" but I'm finding it difficult to find on-line explanations of their many other types of "rapid analytic machinery" which are not shielded by "paywalls."  No, I really am not interested in paying $75.00 (USD) for access to a single article.  Therefore, what books and/or article sources might you recommend?

Comment: Search for `Removing barriers in the way of science`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, kelataka.  I know that David Kahn's book discussed some of the "other" devices (in his recent editions where he knew about them), but I found only one *Cryptologia* article that wants $75.00 just to read it.

Comment: https://9gag.com/gag/aQdVDRz?ref=android